# I cannot Print Images with blue_thermal_printer (Print Random Characters) Flutter

Tags: flutter, printing

what's a problem with my code?

```
   var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/jpg-file-icon-logo-element-illustration-design-155443757.jpg"));
    Uint8List bytesNetwork = response.bodyBytes;
    Uint8List imageBytesFromNetwork = bytesNetwork.buffer.asUint8List();

        await bluetooth.printImageBytes(imageBytesFromNetwork);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering the pixels of your image, I had a similar problem.